# Trouble with updating table with arrays

Tags: php, mysql

After being stuck trying to get a grip of how this works, i've decided to ask for some hints to how I can do this.

Let me start by saying I have next to no experience with anything like this. I've just gathered some logic by looking at the code and i'm almost done with my project, except for this issue that i've come by.

This is the original code (which i am still using another place in the code, this appears to be working just fine).

```
function showCart() {
global $db;
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
if ($cart) {
    $items = explode(',',$cart);
    $contents = array();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
    }
    $output[] = '<form action="kurv.php?action=update" method="post" id="cart">';
    $output[] = '<table>';
    foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM varetabel WHERE varenr = '.$id;
        $result = $db->query($sql);
        $row = $result->fetch();
        extract($row);
        $output[] = '<tr>';
        $output[] = '<td><a href="kurv.php?action=delete&varenr='.$id.'" class="r">Slet</a></td>';
        $output[] = '<td>'.$varenavn.'</td>';
        $output[] = '<td>DKK '.$pris.'</td>';
        $output[] = '<td><input type="text" name="qty'.$id.'" value="'.$qty.'" size="3" maxlength="3" /></td>';
        $output[] = '<td>DKK '.($pris * $qty).'</td>';
        $total += $pris * $qty;
        $output[] = '</tr>';
        $_SESSION['items'] = $contents; // Antal forskellige varer.
        $_SESSION['qty'] = $qty;
    }
    $output[] = '</table>';
    $output[] = '<p>Pris total: <strong>DKK '.$total.'</strong></p>';
    $output[] = '<div><button type="submit">Opdatér kurv</button></div>';
    $output[] = '</form>';
} else {
    $output[] = '<p>Kurven er tom.</p>';
}
return join('',$output);
```

}

global $db is connecting to the DB and such, no biggie, and then there is this function from an include:

```
    function fetch () {
    if ( $row=mysql_fetch_array($this->query,MYSQL_ASSOC) ) {
        return $row;
    } else if ( $this->size() > 0 ) {
        mysql_data_seek($this->query,0);
        return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, im trying to use the same method to take the arrays from this code and put them into my database with this code:

```
session_start();
global $db;
$items = $_SESSION['items'];
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
$qty = $_SESSION['qty'];

if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) { // IF LOGGED IN

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM antalstabel ORDER BY ordrenr DESC LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql);
$maxordrenr = $row['ordrenr'];
$nextnumber = $maxordrenr + 1;
$antal = count($items); // COUNTS DIFFERENT ITEMS IN CART.
$maxplusantal = $maxordrenr + $antal;
$varenrplaceholder = 0;

for ($i = $maxordrenr; $i <= $maxplusantal; $i++) {

$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO antalstabel (ordrenr, varenr) VALUES ('$nextnumber','$varenrplaceholder')") or die(mysql_error());
$nextnumber--;
$varenrplaceholder++;

}

$varenrplaceholder = 0;

if ($cart) {
$items = explode(',',$cart);
$contents = array();

foreach ($items as $item) {

$contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;

}

foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) {

$sql = 'UPDATE antalstabel SET varenr = '.$id.' and antal = '.$qty.' WHERE ordrenr = '.$nextnumber.' and varenr = '.$varenrplaceholder.'';
$result = $db->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch();
extract($row);
$varenrplaceholder++;

}
}
```

But it does not appear to be working properly, the code does run, but it does not update the tabel with the values of the arrays.

Am i completely wrong or can anyone help me with this issue, i know it is a lot to ask.

my own code creates X rows with the same ID depending on how many different items there is in the cart, I am trying to update those existing rows that i've just created with the values i presume is still in the arrays of the `showCart()` function.

Thank you in advance

Comment: which error you are getting?

Comment: Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /mysql.class.php on line 151

Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /mysql.class.php on line 167

Warning: extract() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /bestil.php on line 48

Comment: what you want to fetch from `$result = $db->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch();` you are updating the field not fetching the records

Comment: so the query should be SELECT, and then use that data to update the fields?

Comment: It appears that you are trying to create a new script, yet you have nothing to assign a value to $db. You have based it on a function which is using $db as a global variable. The script you have based it on probably has a line in it saying something like $db = new DatabaseClass($Database, $UserId, $Password); . You need that line instead of Global $db; .

Comment: The script i got the code from actually used "global $db", it's also an include and it does contain the info you stated :) Tried switching it out and had the exact same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is error at your code line

```
foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) {

$sql = 'UPDATE antalstabel SET varenr = '.$id.',antal = '.$qty.' WHERE ordrenr = '.$nextnumber.' and varenr = '.$varenrplaceholder.'';
$varenrplaceholder++;

}

$select_query='SELECT * FROM varetabel WHERE varenr = '.$id;
$result = $db->query($select_query);
$row = $result->fetch();
extract($row);
```

Comment: and yes you should check query get execute successfully

Comment: This did indeed get rid of the mysql errors, however the tabel is still not updating. thank you :)

Comment: There are no errors to display, tried added echo(mysql_error()) and adding ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); on the top of that page, am I doing debugging wrong?

Comment: echo the query and try to run in database directly.

Comment: This is brilliant. This is what it returns UPDATE antalstabel SET varenr = 6 and antal = 1 WHERE ordrenr = 11 and varenr = 0, this looks exactly like what im trying to achieve. I both have a table where ordrenr is 11, and varenr is 0 (which is a primary key, so no duplicates), but running this in the database itself returns with 0 rows affected. Wat.

Comment: can you post the structure of your table

Comment: friend i want structure not data because i want to check vartype

Comment: http://imgur.com/rCKj5Oa Sorry, this is called structure though, hope this is right

Comment: oh my god there is an error in update query how could i made mistake now try :) i edited the update query

Comment: This worked brilliantly, afterall it was actually a syntax error, thank you very, VERY much friend :).

Answer (score 1):

```
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM varetabel WHERE varenr = '.$id;
    $result = $db->query($sql);
```

You aren't checking the success/failure status returned by query().  Most of the MySQL functions return `false` if there's an error, for example a misspelled table name or an invalid expression in the WHERE clause.

I don't know what $id is, but you should inspect the $sql string to see if it works (copy & paste it into a mysql client session to test it).

And you should always check that $result is not `false`.  See http://php.net/mysql_error

Comment: Yes, this was definitely the first problem i had, thank you for clarifying this :)

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be creating a lot of dummy records, then going through an updating them. I would expect you to have just needed to do the insert, but wondering if this is something to do with the fetch you do after the update.

However the main thing that I suspect stops you query working is that you count the number of $items before you have set $items to the exploded $cart.

I have done the following, using assumed names for the methods in your db class

```
<?php
session_start();
global $db;
$items = $_SESSION['items'];
$cart = $_SESSION['cart'];
$qty = $_SESSION['qty'];

if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) 
{ // IF LOGGED IN

    if ($cart) 
    {
        $sql = "SELECT MAX(ordrenr) AS ordrenr FROM antalstabel";
        $result = $db->query($sql) or die($db->error());
        if ($row = $result->fetch())
        {
            $maxordrenr = $row['ordrenr'];
            $nextnumber = $maxordrenr + 1;
            $items = explode(',',$cart);
            $antal = count($items); // COUNTS DIFFERENT ITEMS IN CART.
            $maxplusantal = $maxordrenr + $antal;
            $varenrplaceholder = 0;

            for ($i = $maxordrenr; $i <= $maxplusantal; $i++) 
            {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO antalstabel (ordrenr, varenr) VALUES ('$nextnumber','$varenrplaceholder')";
                $db->query($sql) or die($db->error());
                $varenrplaceholder++;
            }

            $varenrplaceholder = 0;
            $contents = array();

            foreach ($items as $item) 
            {
                $contents[$item] = (isset($contents[$item])) ? $contents[$item] + 1 : 1;
            }

            foreach ($contents as $id=>$qty) 
            {
                $sql = "UPDATE antalstabel SET varenr = $id and antal = $qty WHERE ordrenr = $nextnumber and varenr = $varenrplaceholder";
                $result = $db->query($sql) or die($db->error());
                $row = $result->fetch();
                extract($row);
                $varenrplaceholder++;
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This is definitely better put than what I came up with, i'll format this way instead, it runs smooth if i put in the solution. thank you.